# Prolog gives me the first rule always as an output

Tags: prolog

I have a code about risks being in 3 stages : `high`,`mid`,`low`. I stated the facts and rules correctly as it should be, but for some reason the output is always the my first rule which it "high".
I tried everything couldn't figure out what is the issue, did I do something wrong ?

```
driver_age(young).
driver_age(middle).
driver_age(old).

accident_history(yes).
accident_history(no).

gender(male).
gender(female).

risk(high) :- 
   driver_age(young),
   gender(male),
   accident_history(yes).

risk(mid) :- 
   driver_age(young),
   gender(male),
   accident_history(no).

risk(low) :- 
   driver_age(young),
   gender(male),
   accident_history(no).
```

this is the code I made. It gives me the first rule even if I use something like :

```
risk(X),driver_age(young),gender(male),accident_history(no).
```

the output should be `low` but it's always `high` no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run?

```
risk(X),driver_age(young),gender(male),accident_history(no).
```

Prolog will first look for an `X` such that `risk(X)` is true.

The first acceptable entry going from top down that is found is:

```
risk(high) :- 
   driver_age(young),
   gender(male),
   accident_history(yes).
```

with `X` = `high`.

This is a rule and the rule states that all of `driver_age(young)`, `gender(male)`, `accident_history(yes)` must be true for `risk(high)` to be true.

For each of those, looking through the text from top to bottom, Prolog will indeed find those are true as they are stated explicitly as facts.

So `X` = `high` is a (first) solution to your query as implied by the program. It turns out that `X`= `mid` and `X` = `low` are also solutions, and Prolog will print those when you query more solutions with `;`.

This is evidently not what you want.

You want to query the risk level when the attributes of the driver are:

`driver_age` = `young`, `gender` = `male`, `accident_history` = `no`.

What you need is a predicate:

`risk(Driver, Level) :- ...`

and a way to specify the attributes of a given driver:

`age(john,young).`
`gender(john,male).`
`accident_history(john,no).`

I will not say anything more, try it out on your preferred REPL or on [Swish](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/)